# mandar RadioButton con SendKeys.Send();

Tags: c#, windows-forms, radiobutton

Estoy enviando información desde un windows form a un formulario. El problema que tengo es que el ¿Cómo mandar Radio buttons?

***metodo:***

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFecha.Text);
    string stringFecha = fecha.ToShortDateString();

    //MessageBox.Show(fecha+"\n"+stringFecha);

    ActivateApp("roalrogaSoft");   ///activo el formulario para mendar los datos
    SendKeys.Send(txtCodigo.Text);

    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    SendKeys.Send(txtPaterno.Text);

    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    SendKeys.Send(txtMaterno.Text);

    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    SendKeys.Send(txtNombres.Text);

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo que mandar un Radio Button? ¿No querrás decir mandar el estado (seleccionado o no) de un radio button?

Comment: No se si entiendo muy bien, pero si intentas acceder con tabuladores al radiobutton y despues activarlo, intenta mandar un espacio (`SendKeys.send(" ");`)

Comment: bien, segun mi secuencia, despues del tab va el espacio ?

Comment: habia notado que al hacer tab no selecciona ninguno de los radioButtons, de un textBox se salta al otro sin entrar a los radioButtons

Comment: Eso depende. Cada formulario puede establecer un "tab order", es decir, en que orden se van seleccionando los controles al pulsar tab. Lo que puedes hacer es probar manualmente primero, ir dando a tab hasta que se seleccione lo que quieres y contar cuantos tab fueron necesarios

Comment: en este formulario se salta la seccion de genero, no entra con los tabs, no para mandar espacio ni nada

Comment: prueba hacer un click sobre el radio, y despues rota con tab a ver a donde va a parar el foco. puede que este en otro contenedor, y no lo puedas acceder por teclado desde donde estas.

Comment: Primero: ¿Cuál es el sentido de activar un formulario e ir saltando de control en control? Segundo: Cada control tiene su nombre, puedes dirigirte a cada uno de ellos.